# How do I alter a mysql table column defaults?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, alter

I have a table with a column of type `timestamp` which defaults `current_timestamp` and updates to `current_timestamp` on every update.

I want to remove the "on update" feature on this column.  How do I write the alter statement?

I tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable alter column time  set DEFAULT now();
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: You sure it isn't using a trigger to update it?

Comment: This question should migrate to StackExcange: Database Administrators

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Pete was almost correct but used the wrong syntax for 'change':

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE `time` `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Notice that you must repeat the column name.  Also, make sure you are using backticks instead of single quotes to escape the column name time, which prevents it from being interpreted as the mysql column type of time.

By specifying the DEFAULT of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MySQL will no longer automatically update the column.  From the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

> With a DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clause and no ON UPDATE clause, the column has the current timestamp for its default value but is not automatically updated.

Answer (score 12):

You can't AFAIK use functions such as NOW() as a default.

Try

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHANGE `time` `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

(Edited to add escaping and second use of field name)

Comment: Got the following:
mysql> ALTER TABLE messages CHANGE time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1
mysql> ALTER TABLE messages CHANGE column time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1

Comment: Sorry forgot to add escaping, and the field name comes twice.