# MySql Error: 1364 Field 'display_name' doesn't have default value

Tags: php, mysql

I have just switched from a MAMP installation to a native Apache, MySql and PHP installation. I have got everything working, but I have started using my web app in the new environment and suddenly any INSERT commands are resulting in the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'display_name' doesn't have a default value

It seems the I am unable to leave a field blank now where I was able to before. I am using MySql version 5.6.13

Is there a way to change this setting in MySql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I alter a mysql table column defaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770203/how-do-i-alter-a-mysql-table-column-defaults)

Comment: Is display_name a field with NOT NULL constraint and no default value? Is your insert statement not providing a value for display_name? Knowing your table structure and the insert statement would be helpful.

Comment: Remove the strict settings or set the default values to `NULL`

Comment: I faced same issue , the problem was I created trigger on table and I was not able to delete records from the table and it show same error.after delete trigger it works now.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

MySQL is most likely in STRICT mode.

Try running `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=''` or edit your my.cnf to make sure you aren't setting `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` or the like.

Comment: Is it a bad practice to use strict mode in MySQL?

Comment: Before you do it, you can see current value by this:
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode

Comment: Is this only for  >= 5.7 ?

Answer (score 21):

MySQL is most likely in `STRICT` mode, which isn't necessarily a bad thing, as you'll identify bugs/issues early and not just blindly think everything is working as you intended.

Change the column to allow null:

```
ALTER TABLE `x` CHANGE `display_name` `display_name` TEXT NULL
```

or, give it a default value as empty string:

```
ALTER TABLE `x` CHANGE `display_name` `display_name` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Comment: This is a much better solution.  As a developer, you shouldn't rely on lazy coding.  Know exactly what you are putting into your database at all time.  Strict mode is a great benefit to developers, as it helps identify sloppy code.

Comment: This results in "... TEXT column can't have a default value".

Comment: Empty string is not a valid default value -- it should be a whitespace string `' '`

Answer (score 18):

All of these answers are a good way, but I don't think you want to always go to your DB and modify the default value that you have set to **NULL**.

I suggest you go to the **app/User.php** and modify the `protected $fillable` so it will take your new fields in the data array used to register.

Let's say you add a new input field called `"first_name"`, your `$fillable` should be something like this :

```
protected $fillable = [ 'first_name', 'email', 'password',];
```

This did it for me. Good luck!

Comment: Why are you assuming the OP is using laravel/eloquent?

Comment: This was the gotcha that got me. Will upvote once you mention that this is spcific to Laravel and Eloquent

Comment: $fillable was why I was getting this error message.  Added columns to my table and to the store() method, but forgot to add the column names to $fillable!

Answer (score 6):

I also faced that problem and there are two ways to solve this in laravel.

1. first one is you can set the default value as **null**. I will show you an example:

   ```
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->string('name');
           $table->string('gender');
           $table->string('slug');
           $table->string('pic')->nullable();
           $table->string('email')->unique();
           $table->string('password');
           $table->rememberToken();
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   }
   ```

as the above example, you can set `nullable()` for that feature. then when you are inserting data MySQL set the default value as null.

2. second one is in your model set your input field in `protected $fillable` field. as example:

   ```
   protected $fillable = [
       'name', 'email', 'password', 'slug', 'gender','pic'
   ];
   ```

I think the second one is fine than the first one and also you can set nullable feature as well as fillable in the same time without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Also, I had this issue using Laravel, but fixed by changing my database schema to allow "null" inputs on a table where I plan to collect the information from separate forms:

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('trip_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('trip_id')->unsigned();
        $table->time('est_start');
        $table->time('est_end');
        $table->time('act_start')->nullable();
        $table->time('act_end')->nullable();
        $table->date('Trip_Date');
        $table->integer('Starting_Miles')->nullable();
        $table->integer('Ending_Miles')->nullable();
        $table->string('Bus_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('Event');
        $table->string('Desc')->nullable();
        $table->string('Destination');
        $table->string('Departure_location');
        $table->text('Drivers_Comment')->nullable();
        $table->string('Requester')->nullable();
        $table->integer('driver_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

}
```

The ->nullable(); Added to the end.  This is using Laravel.  Hope this helps someone, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I forgot to add new **form fields/database columns** to the `$fillable` array in the Laravel model - the model was stripping them out.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue using Lumen, but fixed by setting  `DB_STRICT_MODE=false` in `.env` file.