# MySQL update default value of column in multiple tables from an inner select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, information-schema, subquery

I need to update the default value of all `Synced` fields in a database tables.

I've looked at several other posts and put together the following, which I'm missing something, any ideas?

```
ALTER TABLE (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT
      TABLE_NAME
  FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA != 'mysql'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA != 'information_schema'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Synced'
  ORDER BY 
    TABLE_NAME ASC)
CHANGE `Synced` `Synced` TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
```

I've referenced the following to put it together:

- [MySQL, update multiple tables with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361774/mysql-update-multiple-tables-with-one-query)
- [How do I alter a mysql table column defaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770203/how-do-i-alter-a-mysql-table-column-defaults)

Comment: You cannot use a subquery for a table definition.  To do what you want, you need to generate SQL in a string variable and then use `prepare` and `execute` to run the statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want some dynamic SQL. Like this:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' CHANGE `Synced` `Synced` TINYINT DEFAULT 0;') 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA != 'mysql'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA != 'information_schema'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Synced'
ORDER BY 
    TABLE_NAME ASC
```

Comment: I updated the code to include `DISTINCT` in the query. Is there a way to execute each of these dynamic queries after building them, in sql, not in code.