# Set default value to all columns in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working in a PHP + MySQL application. The application is working fine for me. But when I hosted it in another server, I got a MySQL error:

> Error Code: 1364. Field 'field' doesn't have a default value

I know this is a problem with the MySQL version and we should setup default values for all columns. But currently I have more than 100 tables. So I need to set default value to `NULL` for all columns in all tables that has no default value yet.

I can't make use of the `strict mode` option, because the server is a shared one. Is it possible to setup in a single step rather than setting for each and every table ? If not possible tell me the easiest way to setup it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Someone down-voted the question. Don't know why ?

Comment: I mitigated that, your question isn't that bad ;) To fix it on the DB side without changing the mode, You have to ALTER your columns to give them a default value. [How do I alter a mysql table column defaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770203/how-do-i-alter-a-mysql-table-column-defaults) might be helpful.

Comment: hmm..okay.. is it possible in a single query for the whole database ?

Comment: No, but it's possible to manipulate the DDL SQL script to add some `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` using mass string replacements  or column edition mode (using UltraEdit or Notepad++). That's a tactic I am using pretty often to overcome such issues.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else with this problem, it will take a bit of coding to perform automatically, but the following would be how you would do so:

First run the following query:

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name,column_name,data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE IS_NULLABLE='NO' AND column_default is null AND column_key=''
```

Next, for each row returned from the above query perform the following:

```
If data_type contains 'int' set default to 0
else if data_type='datetime' set default to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
else if data_type='date' set default to '0000-00-00'
else if data_type='time' set default to '00:00:00'
else set default to ''
```

create and run the following query with all [[...]] variables replaced with their proper values:

```
ALTER TABLE `[[table_schema]]`.`[[table_name]]` ALTER COLUMN `[[column_name]]` SET DEFAULT '[[default]]'
```

This should replace the default values for all databases, all tables, all columns that are set to be NOT NULL and are not primary keys and have no default value set.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that i found is like:-

Get all column name put it in array...
Now push values in column array for inserting -- with ZERO value for all those arrays we do not have values.
FOR EXAMPLE:
in a table we have COLUMN
NAME LASTNAME COMPNAME PHONO EMAIL ADDRESS ALTERPERSON ALTERPHONE ALTEREMAIL
Now after migration we see the eeror

> Error Code: 1364. Field 'field' doesn't have a default value

if we run a INSERT QUERY LIKE

> mysqli_query($con,'insert into table
>   (NAME,LASTNAME,COMPNAME,PHONO,EMAIL,ADDRESS) values
>   (NAME,LASTNAME,COMPNAME,PHONO,EMAIL,ADDRESS)')

now it will give error...

So just turn the table
get all the column value from DB.TABLE
put it in an array or do it like one by one using while loop or for loop....

check insert values for each column
put condition if insert value is equal to ZERO or NULL then  insert ZERO it will solve all issues.

## WHY ZERO --

because it will work for VARCHAR,TEXT,INT,BIGINT and in many Data Types except time or date function and DATE/TIME data type got ZERO values by default...

## =============================== Another option...

run a PHP code
get all TABLE NAME
then for each TABLE NAME
get all COLUMN NAME

## and run this command as in function under loop

> ALTER TABLE DB.TABLEnAME CHANGE `columnNAME_A` `columnNAME_A`
>   VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL
>   DEFAULT NULL;

=======================

And its DONE